# Autocomplete & Datepicker Library Confliction

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, datepicker

I have created an auto complete function that works fine, and a datepicker that also works fine, however when I try and put both of them on the same page I get an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function(anonymous function)
@ quote2.php:22(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:2299(anonymous function) 
@ jquery.js:2319jQuery.extend.each @ jquery.js:745jQuery.extend.ready 
@ jquery.js:2318
```

That above is the error I get when using inspect on Google chrome. I suspect it is a confliction between the two Jquery libraries

Below is the datepicker and autocomplete combined

```
<?php session_start(); ob_start(); require_once "delivery/config.php"; ?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Academic Education V2 | Pages | Portfolio</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

```
<link href="layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="delivery/jquery.autocomplete.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="delivery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="delivery/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="delivery/autocomplete.js"></script>

</head>
<script> $(function() {  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate:0}); 
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "DD, d MM, yy" );    });    </script>
```

these are the links incase you want to see what the imports are: Jquery is version 1.2.6
http://www.acehire.co.uk/delivery/jquery.js

http://www.acehire.co.uk/delivery/jquery.autocomplete.js

As I put at the top, they work individually fine, I have tried either jquery library instead of both and get errors, its probably something simple, but I cannot work out how to get it to work. I have also tried removing certain imports etc, and cannot get it to work correctly. When i run the page as it is the autocomplete is fine, but not the datepicker.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Alex

Comment: Why are you importing `jQuery` twice?

Comment: When I created both of them, they used different versions of Jquery, 1.2.6 and 1.10.2, I know one needs taking out, but there is still something wrong after I remove the older version

Comment: @AlexioHill with 2 versions of JQuery being used, there may be all sorts of problems. Are you using Jquery UI, what version, or some other plugin?

Comment: Unable to replicate your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3134efst/

Comment: code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js so version 1.11.4, please see [link](http://www.acehire.co.uk/quote2.php) i have now removed the older version of Jquery, and it gives an error about Opera from jquery.autocomplete.js:83. The link provided should show it better.

Comment: [link](http://www.acehire.co.uk/quote3.php) shows autocomplete working
[link](http://www.acehire.co.uk/quote4.php) shows datepicker working
[link](http://www.acehire.co.uk/quote2.php) has date picker working, but autocomplete failing on "Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined"

Comment: It seems that `jquery.autocomplete.js` is outdated and it cannot work with newer version (it use `$.browser` that was deprecated since [1.3](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)). Maybe you can use an updated version of the same library or jQuery UI [automplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: That was the conclusion I was starting to come to, JPicker needed a new Jquery library and Autocomplete an old one. I have completely re-written the Autocomplete to work with a newer Jquery and hence JPicker works with that. Thanks for your help!